# Force on body = multiple?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

**Context**

"Force" is assumed to equal "mass" times acceleration.

$$
\textbf{F} = {m \textbf{a}} \tag{1}
$$

Precisely, acceleration is Force divided by mass.

$$
\textbf{a} = {\textbf{F} \over m} \tag{2}
$$

More precisely, acceleration of a "point" having mass $m$ is (2).

Additionally, any Force acts only on a "particle" having mass (3).

**Situation**

"A Force" is pulling on a body. More precisely "Gravity" is pulling on a body.
When disjunct points each are pulled on, each point is accelerated according to (2).

Considering (3) Gravity acts on the particles the body is made of.
Assuming each of these particles is a point having mass equal the mass every other of these particles has, each particle is accelerated equally.

$M$ = mass of body
$N$ = number of particles body is made of assuming each of them is a point having mass equal the mass every other of them has

$$
\textbf{a}_{particle} = {\textbf{F} \over {M \over N}} = N {\textbf{F} \over M} \tag{4}
$$

Every particle accelerating equally, the volume they occupy accelerates equally.
Is this volume the body appearing to accelerate ?
And is "the body accelerating" thus by (4) ?

(4) $= {N \textbf{F} \over M}$ is the reason for the title "Force on body = multiple ?"

Considering objects on earth are known to be made of "few" "things" occupying volume (but not assuming the number of kind of particle in (3) is 1) $N$ might be the same value for every object. Thus "is earths gravity determined too big by a factor of billions?".

Comment: It sounds like you are considering some combination of Higg's bosons and gravitons. How did you arrive at the final "thus", though? Why would this description lead to Earth's gravity being determined as "too big"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the situation here as you have presented focuses on how the earth pulls upon one particle whose mass is the total mass divided by number of particles represented as M/N, and the force as F. And then you said because the acceleration is the same for the small particle, it should also apply for the object at large because the object is not expanding or shrinking in anyway. And so far, the reasoning is on the right track but has some issues.

The issue with this is the force changing because you are dealing with an individual particle instead of the whole mass. The calculation you have shown says the gravitational force applied to the entire mass with its entire magnitude, also applies to each individual particle with its entire magnitude. This is where the issue comes from because the force actually decreases because equation for gravity is net F=Fg=mg. So actually for the equation you derived, Fg would be M/N times g because that is the force on each individual particle. Then if you solve for acceleration, you get M/N times g divided by M/N for mass and you a=g which is as you would expect if the object was in free fall.

So all in all we just derived above that the individual accelerations are actually g down so now we can extrapolate that since individual accelerations are g down, it means the entire acceleration of the object is g down because the object isn't changing shape or size.

So no, Earth's gravity is not too big; it perfectly matches the correct gravitational acceleration

Comment: My error was Gravity is not equal for all when expressed as a force; particle and body both experience gravitation but their Gravityforce is ~ m_1 * m_2 (1 being earth, 2 being object). Thus F in acceleration for particle is different from F in acceleration for body (and acceleration and Force are of the same object in (2)), mass of particle can still be replaced by M/N but so it has to be done for m_2 in the "Gravityforce", but m_2 being cancelled out by its division through m_2 in the acceleration equation, replacing's superfluous, "g" is yielded.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you give that yields $a_{particle}=N\frac F M$ is misleading because it implies that the whole $F$ is being imparted to a single particle.

If I take a step back and write it as $a_{particle}=\frac{F_{particle}}{M_{particle}}$, and apply the same $M_{particle}=\frac{M}{N}$ that you did, I get $a_{particle}=\frac{F_{particle}}{\frac M N}=N\frac{F_{particle}}{M}$.  This is almost what you wrote, except note that the force is only the force applied to the particle.  If the force is applied equally across all particles, you get $a_{particle}=N\frac{\frac{F}{N}}{M} = \frac F M$

Comment: when 2 humans are pulled by Gravity, is the Gravity on each human G/2 according to your F/N ? If not, what's the difference to Gravity pulling the same Gravity on every particle which interacts with Gravity (and those particles happen to make up the body)?

Comment: @user5588495 In the way you laid out the question, it looks like F as the total force, as you divided the particles up later.  As such, my answer uses F in the same way.  F is the force of gravity upon two people, and F/2 is the force of gravity upon one person.  You can do it the other way too.  You can define F to be the force on one person, and then NF is the combined force on N people.  You just need to be consistent with your meaning of F once you start.

Comment: Many a physics student has been lead astray by starting with F=ma because it looks like a useful equation, and then grabbing an arbitrary F, and an unrelated m, and lo and behold, the result doesn't yield a meaningful acceleration.